# Cannot render publications list using Vitae

Tags: knitr, google-scholar, tinytex

I am having trouble getting my publication list to render in my CV using `vitae`. I have read a previous post *https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae/issues/70* but cannot resolve the issue with the information provided. I have tried deleting the *.tex file in the output folder. I have tried updating my version of `vitae` to the latest version. New to R so appreciate pointers on where I am going wrong, thanks.

```
scholar::get_publications("EmD_lTEAAAAJ&EmD_lTEAAAAJ&") %>% 
  filter(cites > 30) %>% 
  distinct(title, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  transmute(bibtype = "Article", author = as.character(author),
            title = as.character(title),
            journaltitle = as.character(journal), year, key = row_number()) %>% 
  RefManageR::as.BibEntry() %>% 
  RefManageR::WriteBib("curie.bib")

bibliography_entries("curie.bib")
```

Error message:

```
Can't decode ill-formed UTF-8 octet sequence <E9> at C:\Users\nicho\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6e6963686f\cache-3fdda9ab9b6106ff01fe44df85bbc368a2e8d9e0\inc\lib/File/Slurper.pm line 59.
Error: Failed to build the bibliography via biber
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.3 
2: In RefManageR::as.BibEntry(.) :
  rownames of data.frame not meaningful for creating keys
Execution halted
Warning message:
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 194.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '1' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '2' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '3' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '4' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '5' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '6' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '7' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '8' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '9' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '10' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '11' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '12' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '13' undefined on input line 209.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '14' undefined on input line 209.
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `Untitled.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)     [... truncated]
```

Comment: What error occurs?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I just updated it now with the error message. Thanks